# Q: Where do I get security patches for CentOS 6.7/6.5

Tags: centos, centos6.5

I just wanted to ask if there is a website where CentOs security patches are released. I am having trouble finding it in google though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link which stats whole process about installing security updates on CentOS

[Security Updates](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-security-updates.html)